# AVerTV Hybrid Volar HD H830

Tags: linux, debian

I need to install this card on Linux?

I can't find any driver for it -> https://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/AVerMedia

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried and supply as many details as possible. E.g., the linked website lists this device with an USB interface, support is marked as "partial" and a corresponding driver link. What did you achieve when using this driver? What's the output of `lsusb -vvv` of the device.

Answer (score 1):

Googling for "Linux brand product-name model-number" usually finds relevant info.

e.g. [Linux AVerTV Hybrid Volar HD H830](https://www.google.com/search?q=Linux+AVerTV+Hybrid+Volar+HD+H830) shows several results, one of which from **Sep 2012** says:

> (http://www.iecl.univ-lorraine.fr/~Olivier.Garet/linux/notes_installation_av830_debian.php):
>
> Unfortunately, there is no open driver, I think.
>
> AVerMedia releases a version of a closed driver which is tested for Ubuntu.
>
> The autoinstaller fails on debian because [...]

If that doesn't give you enough useful info, or if the info seems old and possibly out-of-date, then you can try googling for the hardware id.

If the device is installed in your linux box, you can run `lsusb` to find the device's vendor id and product id, then google for `linux vendor:product`.

e.g. my main myth box has a Digital Now Quad DVB-T card in it.  Four USB DVB tuners soldered on to a PCI-e 1x USB adaptor card.

`lsusb` shows it as:

```
Bus 010 Device 005: ID 0413:6680 Leadtek Research, Inc. 
Bus 010 Device 004: ID 0413:6680 Leadtek Research, Inc. 
Bus 010 Device 003: ID 0413:6680 Leadtek Research, Inc. 
Bus 010 Device 002: ID 0413:6680 Leadtek Research, Inc.
```

If i didn't already know it had a working linux driver, I'd google for "[linux 0413:6680](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+0413%3A6680)".

That will at least give a good starting point for figuring out if it's supported by linux, or whether anyone is working on a driver.

---

(*) or maybe `lspci` if it isn't a USB device, but most TV tuner devices **are** USB...even those that plug directly into a PCI/PCI-e slot are usually USB devices soldered to a PCI/PCI-e USB card.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, and sorry for my small information. ~$ lsusb

Bus 002 Device 004: ID 07ca:c830 AVerMedia Technologies, Inc.

Comment: I got this driver: http://storage.avermedia.com/web_release_www/A867R/A867R_drv_v1.0.29_20160707.tar.bz2 but I can't install this on Debian Stretch.

Comment: "$ make
Missing files that required to build driver: /lib/modules/4.9.0-4-amd64/source/drivers/media/dvb/dvb-usb/dvb-usb-common.h dvb-usb/dvb-usb.h dvb-usb/dvb-usb-ids.h dvb-core/dvb_frontend.h dvb-core/dvbdev.h dvb-core/dmxdev.h dvb-core/dvb_demux.h dvb-core/dvb_net.h dvb-core/demux.h dvb-core/dvb_ringbuffer.h frontends/dvb-pll.h
Try to get kernel source closest to 4.9.0-4-amd64 from http://www.kernel.org and then copy to /lib/modules/4.9.0-4-amd64/source/drivers/media/dvb"

"$ uname -r
4.9.0-4-amd64"

"/lib/modules/4.9.0-4-amd64/source/drivers/media/dvb" -> I don't have this.